# Dictionary key case gets converted to lower case when rendered in client side after http.get request

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, http-get

I have a dictionary object inside a class. I am going to render this class in Client side using http.get request.

```
prt = $http.get(baseUrl() + "api/flight/" + id)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $rootScope.flight = data;                      
          return data;
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          return data;
      });
```

The dictionary named fuelRate is defined a below

```
private static Dictionary<string, decimal> _fuelRates;
public static Dictionary<string, decimal> fuelRates
{
    get
    {
        if (_fuelRates == null)
        {
            using (flightDBEntities flightDBEntities = new flightDBEntities(ConnectionStringManager.SQLConnection))
            {
                var convRate = flightDBEntities.fuelRates.Select(x => new { x.UnitName, x.UnitRate }).ToList();
                _fuelRates = convRate == null ? new Dictionary<string, decimal>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) : convRate.ToDictionary(cr => cr.UnitName, cr => cr.UnitRate ?? 1, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }
        }

        return _fuelRates;
    }
    set
    {
        _fuelRates = value;
    }
}
```

Data is retrieved from DB and data is as below:

```
UnitName   unitRate
Cent       100
Ton    1000
Gallon     10000
```

Here the case Unit name start with Upper case. 
But once it is rendered in client side, the case get converted to all lower case and Unit name will read as below

```
UnitName   unitRate
cent       100
ton    1000
gallon     10000
```

Is there a way I can restrict this from happening.

Comment: So have you looked at what's coming over the network? That's where I'd start, so you can tell whether the problem is client-side or server-side.

Comment: I checked the server side. It was coming properly till the last point. But as soon as it reached client side it got converted to lower case

Comment: But that doesn't say what's coming *over the network*. You haven't shown us how you're sending that dictionary over the network, but there's likely to be some sort of code being used that's not in *your* code, and is after whatever point you were last able to debug. If you know what's coming over the network (e.g. by watching the request/response in Chrome) then you'll be in a much stronger position to work out where the problem is.

Comment: The issue looks to be on the client side. I used fiddler to see the request/response. When the response reaches the Client, the first character of all property gets converted to lowercase. This is happening for all properties and only the first character

Comment: Right - so for test purposes, you can have a simple static file to return the JSON, and start debugging in the Javascript.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any suggestions on what could be the issue?

Comment: No, I don't know much about Javascript handling, and you've shown very little code - it's hard to know exactly how the binding is happening. But I'd suggest removing the C# tag as at this point it doesn't seem to be related to the C# code at all.